# Using OVER() in a query that has a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL 2012

I'm using OFFSET and FETCH NEXT for paging in a query. I do need the overall count though so, I'm using OVER() to get the overall count. The problem I'm having is that when I have a UNION in one of my queries, OVER() will return the total for that part of the UNION.

Example:

```
SELECT something
      ,overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM tbl_something
WHERE something = @someparameter

UNION

SELECT something
      ,overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM tbl_something
WHERE something = @someOtherParameter

OFFSET (@intPage - 1) * 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

In the example above, if there is 10 result for each SELECT statement in the query, overall_count will return as 10 for each record. But I need the count of all the records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to combine the 2 queries then get your count and offset

```
SELECT *, 
       overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM (
    SELECT something
    FROM tbl_something
    WHERE something = @someparameter
    UNION
    SELECT something
    FROM tbl_something
    WHERE something = @someOtherParameter
) u
ORDER BY something
OFFSET (@intPage - 1) * 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

or you can use a cte if it makes more sense

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT something
    FROM   tbl_something
    WHERE  something = @someparameter
    UNION
    SELECT something
    FROM   tbl_something
    WHERE  something = @someOtherParameter
)
SELECT *, 
       overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM   cte
ORDER BY something
OFFSET (@intPage - 1) * 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping an additional Select Statement around your union? like below...

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT something
         ,overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
   FROM tbl_something
   WHERE something = @someparameter

   UNION

   SELECT something
         ,overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
   FROM tbl_something
   WHERE something = @someOtherParameter
) a

ORDER BY something
OFFSET (@intPage - 1) * 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I have, but it doesn't seem to help... unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: [OFFSET FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg699618%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) requires an `ORDER BY` clause. Did you include one right before your `OFFSET` clause?

Comment: @jradich1234 you're still not getting the total count for all of the records for each row..

Comment: I didn't know the ORDER BY was required. I didn't include them in my example because I didn't know it was relevant, but it is in my queries

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT something
      ,overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM tbl_something
WHERE something in (@someparameter, someOtherParameter) 
order by something 
OFFSET (@intPage - 1) * 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```